# hibernate query for Getting json key value pair with joins

Tags: mysql, json, rest, hql

I am using REST , hibernate query language for getting some data from database with the help of joins in that query i need to fetch columns from two or more tables and i am getting the result record , and when i return that object through REST as  json i am getting the json as in the follwoing format

> `{"table1col1value","table2col1value","table3colvalue","table1col2value","table2col2value"}`

but i need to get the json data in the following format

> `{"table1colname1":"table1col1value","table2colname":"table2col1value","table1colname":"table3colvalue","table1colname":"table1col2value","table2colname":"table2col2value"}`

for that i am using the following code and its working fine, but its working with sql query only i need it in HQL , please help me in this.

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public List<Map<String,Object>> getMixProperties(List<String> keys,Set<String> s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("select ");
    Iterator<String> i = keys.iterator();
    int q = keys.size();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        q=q-1;
        if(q==0){
            String n= i.next();
            sb.append(" "+n);
        }
        else{
            String n2= i.next();
            sb.append(" "+n2+",");}
    }
    sb.append(" from Book Book "
            + " join Systems Systems ON Systems.idSystems =Book.idSystems "
            + " join Machine Machine ON Machine.id =Systems.id ");
    /*Iterator<String> iterator = s.iterator();
    int q2 = s.size();String s5 = null;
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String s4 = iterator.next();
        q2=q2-1;
        if(q2==0){
            sb.append(" "+s4+" "+s4);
        }
        else{
            s5=s4;
            sb.append(" "+s4+" "+s4+",");}
    }*/
    System.out.println("query "+sb);
    String sbb = sb.toString();
    Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sbb);
    query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
    List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=query.list(); 
    return aliasToValueMapList;
}
```

in this above code List keys will be the column name of different tables and (set s will be table names, but i am not using it in current code)

even this is working only if i have both class and db table name are same and property and column names are same, if its not same then its not working.

I am getting JSON only if i have the pojo class , but in my case result set can be any number of columns so its depends on runtime only , please help me in this